# Garbage collection when compiling to C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, garbage-collection

What are the techniques of garbage collection when compiling a garbage collected language to C? I know of two:

1. maintain a shadow stack that saves all roots explicitly in a data structure
2. use a conservative garbage collector like Boehm's

The first technique is slow, because you have to maintain the shadow stack. Potentially every time a function is called, you need to save the local variables in a data structure.

The second technique is also slow, and inherently does not reclaim all garbage because of using a conservative garbage collector.

My question is: what is the state of the art of garbage collection when compiling to C. Note that I do not mean a convenient way to do garbage collection when programming in C (this is the goal of Boehm's garbage collector), just a way to do garbage collection when *compiling to C*.

Comment: This is a nasty one. It's also why e.g. LLVM and C-- are popular (they allow garbage collection without dealing with it maually).

Comment: Is the type system in the originating language based on DAGs or general graphs? DAGs only need reference counting (as a consequence of being acyclic).

Comment: General graphs, unfortunately. I also thought about reference counting, but that doesn't seem to solve everything because you still need a way to traverse the roots to collect cycles...

Comment: What does it mean to compile *to* C? Can you give a sample command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Potentially every time a function is called, you need to save the local variables in a data structure.

No, you don't - you can leave the local variables on the C stack and still iterate through them: put all reference variables in an array and add a pointer to that to a linked list to which you append a node when entering a new stack frame.

Mockup:

```
struct vm
{
    struct scope *root;
};

struct scope
{
    struct scope *prev, *next;
    size_t size;
    struct ref *refs;
};

void foo(struct vm *vm, struct scope *caller)
{
    struct ref local_refs[42];
    struct scope scope = {
        caller, NULL, sizeof local_refs / sizeof *local_refs, local_refs };

    caller->next = &scope;

    // ...

    caller->next = NULL;
}
```

However, you'll have to jump through some major hoops if you want to support continuations/non-local jumps. In that case, it's easier to heap-allocate everything.

Comment: This kind of technique is most useful when you're using C as a target language for a compiler for some other language, as its error prone and requires carefully keeping track of everything

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting technique. However doesn't this mean that local variables don't live in registers, which is most likely even slower than saving locals when making a call?

Comment: @Jules: the compiler is still free to cache any local value in registers for computations, but you're right, it has to sync the values on function call; I'll have to think about how aproptiate use of `const` and `restrict` could improve the situation by telling the compiler that the called function won't modify the locals...