# Algorithm to have garbage collection when compiling to c

Tags: c, algorithm, garbage-collection, compiler-construction

I need some sort of algorithm to add garbage collection to my language (which is being compiled to c) and add a free statement or some other way so that it will have no memory leaks.

Yes, I looked at [Garbage collection when compiling to C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603701/garbage-collection-when-compiling-to-c), but I do not understand the answer, and was hoping to get a more detailed answer on how to do it.

EDIT: for example if the code is

```
int *i = malloc(4);
```

in my language, this should be compiled to

```
int *i = malloc(4);
```

and then

```
free(i);
```

once i is no longer in use or out of the stack frame
Thanks

Comment: Is your language implementation open source? Where is the C code? Please give some URL!

Comment: That is *not* how most garbage collector works!

Comment: could you please explain how garbage collectors work, I am having trouble understanding and am fairly new to compiler design

Comment: ...or you could just steal the code from the GoLang runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need to read the [garbage collection handbook](https://gchandbook.org/).

You later need to document, in written English, the conventions and invariants of your garbage collector. Is it a generational GC? Is it multi-thread friendly? Is it precise or conservative?

The book by C.Queinnec [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521545668) is helpful. It describes how to code various Lisp interpreters, and some Lisp to C compiler. Some chapters are related to garbage collection and their relation to generated C code.

The [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) (about compilation) has a chapter on GC.

A.Appel's book [*Compiling with Continuations*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521416957) is also helpful.

You then could *document* and probably define *macros* implementing your GC conventions.

Notice that `malloc` could be considered as a slow way of allocating garbage collected data. Read for example Appel's old paper [*Garbage Collection can be faster than Stack allocation*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/002001908790175X) (it was debated later, but it does give a good intuition). You could consider fetching large memory zones with [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and allocating inside them in some faster way. Then you won't `free` individual garbage values (if you adopt a copying GC strategy, using [Cheney's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheney%27s_algorithm)), but will [munmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html) a large memory zone at once. Study also the C source code of `malloc` implementation inside [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl libc](https://musl.libc.org/).

See my [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) project as an example of C code (open source, for Linux) with GC.

Look also inside the C code of [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) interpreter and compiler.

Or inside the C runtime of [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) or of [Chicken/Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_(Scheme_implementation)).

Or inside the code of some open source [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines).

The [Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Manuel.Serrano/bigloo/) project is a Lisp to C compiler.

The [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) editor contains a garbage collector. The [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler also contains [one](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Type-Information.html).

[Circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) are difficult to handle with [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) schemes.

Consider also using [Boehm conservative garbage collector](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/) open source library.

Your GC will be operating system specific, and probably target processor specific.

The [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project (in C++, with generation of C++ code at runtime) has a GC.

At last, the [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) utility (a tool to detect memory leaks) is open source and can be considered as containing some GC.

Read also recent papers submitted to [ACM SIGPLAN](https://sigplan.org/) conferences. Several of them are related to [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). Consider later submitting your own paper on GC.

### Budget several years of full time work.

PS. As an introduction, read the old paper by P.Wilson [*Uniprocessor Garbage Collection Techniques*](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Paul-Wilson-22/publication/225216046_Uniprocessor_Garbage_Collection_Techniques/links/5570624c08aee1eea7586fcb/Uniprocessor-Garbage-Collection-Techniques.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

With good weight, **@Basile Starynkevitch** is right; the subject of garbage collection is a large and thorny field of study and science with all that entails! When constructing a memory-managed language, there is much understanding to be done.

However, you're probably fine simply using *something* without fully understanding its implications if you are creating a new language (especially if it's a personal and/or learning project), with the intention of really spending a good amount of time identifying the best garbage collection strategy in the future.

As is frequently the case in computer science (time vs memory), different garbage collection strategies will involve some suffering and bad cases, and you will want to understand, document, and minimize these cases.

A simple garbage collector for you to implement might be a [reference counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Advantages_and_disadvantages)-based one

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're interested in a static memory allocation based on a region analysis.

You can take a look at MLKit implementation of this approach.